# Changing amount of resource sets in Seize-block programmatically

Tags: anylogic

So the problem is:

How can I change the amount in "Resource Sets" programmatically? I'am planning on changing this value back and forth from 1 and 2 given some conditions during the simulation run.

Amount I want to change is marked in yellow below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emile answer is right, but if you insist in using what you are using, you can click on the equal sign and make it a function:

[image: resource set]

and in the function (which i made take a random number between 1 and 2, but you can do what you want), you use the following (the function returns a type ResourcePool[][])

```
ResourcePool[][] rp = new ResourcePool[1][num];

for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    rp[0][i]=resourcePool;
}
return rp;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it seems you are using one resource alternative only.
Why don't you choose `units of the same pool`, then the number of units to be seized becomes dynamic.